# Error compiling simple c++ hello world for Android

Tags: builds

I'm using Archlinux and I have a simple C++ file `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to compile it to run on *Android*.

I download *Android NDK*, and I follow the instructions on the official website https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems#non-autoconf_make_projects

I run:

```
export NDK=/home/myuser/dnsmasq-Android/android-ndk-r26b/
export ANDROID_NDK=$NDK
export NDK_PROJECT_PATH=$NDK
export TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
export PATH=$TOOLCHAIN/bin:$PATH

export TARGET=armv7a-linux-androideabi
export API=34
```

The path `$TOOLCHAIN/bin` now gives me access to the compiler executable `armv7a-linux-androideabi34-clang++`.

But if I run `armv7a-linux-androideabi34-clang++ main.cpp`, I get the error:

```
clang-17: error: no input files
```

What am I doing wrong?